# How to parcel List<Int> with kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, parcelable, parcel

I want to pass a data class (that contains list of int as a property) to other activity through Bundle and therefore i need to add Parcelable implementation to my data class.
any idea about how to parcel this property?

```
data class Test(val id: Long, val files: List<Int>?) : Parcelable {

constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readLong(),
        TODO("files"))

override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    parcel.writeLong(id)
}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
}

companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Test> {
    override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Test {
        return Test(parcel)
    }

    override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Test?> {
        return arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can write a list of integers as `int[]`:

```
parcel.writeIntArray(files.toIntArray())
```

Make sure you use the same data structure when reading back:

```
files = parcel.createIntArray().toList()
```

You could make it more efficient using extension functions by skipping the array representation:

```
parcel.writeIntList(files)
files = parcel.createIntList()

fun Parcel.writeIntList(input:List<Int>) {
    writeInt(input.size) // Save number of elements.
    input.forEach(this::writeInt) // Save each element.
}

fun Parcel.createIntList() : List<Int> {
    val size = readInt()
    val output = ArrayList<Int>(size)
    for (i in 0 until size) {
        output.add(readInt())
    }
    return output
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have same problem i have followed your way but still getting an error, will you please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58976896/how-to-implement-parcelable-for-listinteger

Answer (score 16):

Kotlin's `@Parcelize` annotation handles lists; you just need to make sure the list items implement the `Parcelable` interface as well:

```
@Parcelize
data class MyDataClass(
    val items: List<MyListItem>?
) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class MyListItem(
    var type: String?,
    var itemId: Long = 0
) : Parcelable
```

Comment: This also needs`id 'kotlin-parcelize'` inside plugins at build.gradle (app).